# Route53 Failover For Multiple Target Groups Behind ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

As per my understanding, Route53 failover can be triggered via evaluating the target health of a AWS resource or via Route53 health checks (i.e. calculated, endpoint, cloudwatch).

Currently, we have the following configuration for the PRIMARY Route53 alias record:

```
Route53 -> NLB -> ALB -> Target Group 1 -> Lambda 1
                      -> Target Group 2 -> Lambda 2
```

We're using a failover routing policy, where the SECONDARY route53 points to another NLB in another region. We're using `evaluate target health` to drive failover.

Also, per my understanding of AWS docs, if any target group is unhealthy, the entire ALB is marked as unhealthy and the primary Route53 record pointing to it is marked as unhealthy.

In other words, using this networking configuration, if I have several independent lambda services behind a single ALB and one of them becomes unhealthy, then Route53 will failover to another region?

The behavior I need is that if one of the lambdas becomes unhealthy, then its requests get routed to the other region, while all other lambda requests continue going to the primary region.

Comment: Are all of these Lambda functions accessed via different paths but using a single hostname pointing to the load balancer?

Comment: That's correct, Michael.

Comment: *"if one of the lambdas becomes unhealthy, then its requests get routed to the other region, while all other lambda requests continue going to the primary region."* That's impossible with this configuration.  Forget about health check integrations for a moment and assume we were hiring someone to just sit and use the console to reconfigure Route 53 as needed based on the health of the Lambdas.  How would they configure Route 53 to send some traffic *for a single hostname* to one region, but other traffic *for the same hostname* to another region?  The answer is... no DNS service can do this.

Comment: There are a couple of interesting potential solutions but before I go down that road I want to ensure that you see the problem I see, and that I'm not misunderstanding what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Michael, is that not what a FAILOVER policy does? Not sure I understand the point you're making, but if you'd like to make design suggestions, feel free. We'll be doing a POC to understand how this all works.

Comment: Yes, that's what the failover policy does... but the reason the entire ALB is marked as unhealthy is that there's no possible way to alternate-route only *some* of the traffic, at the DNS layer. Where all the traffic destined for  `api.example.com` is routed, using DNS routing, is an all-or-nothing decision.  DNS determines which load balancer handles **all** traffic for a given hostname.  DNS is unaware of paths.  The load balancer makes the path-based routing decisions *after* the request arrives, so once a request arrives, the balancer must be prepared to handle it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure does, Michael. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current architecture, the health of ALB is treated as an aggregate of the target groups it points to.

To manage failover for Lambda functions independently, you will neet to change the architecture.

Two options I can think of:

1. Separate ALBs with Route53 evaluating each one independently.
2. Configure CloudWatch alarms for each of your Lambda functions. When a function becomes unhealthy, an alarm will trigger a Route53 health check, which will then cause Route53 to reroute traffic to the failover region.

The second option provides a more granular approach at the cost of higher configuration/management overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your response @nickdoesstuff. For (1), if I keep one NLB and have separate ALBs for each lambda, will that achieve isolated failover? Or are you saying each lambda service should have its own Route53/NLB/ALB setup in front of it (i.e. don't club services behind a common network infrastructure)?

Comment: If you have multiple ALBs behind a single NLB, the NLB will be marked as unhealthy if any of the ALBs behind it is unhealthy. This is similar to how an ALB treats its target groups.

If you want truly isolated failover for each Lambda service, you should not club them behind common network infrastructure. Each Lambda service should have its own Route53, NLB, and ALB setup.